# Centrar de forma vertical en un Constraint Layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Buenas noches a todos,

Estoy creando una aplicación para practicar con los Constraint Layout y me gustaría saber como puedo centrar verticalmente los cuatro elementos que tengo, os dejo el código del XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intridici il tixti"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etBeforeTranslate"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAfterTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Intridici il tixti"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etBeforeTranslate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAfterTranslate"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAfterTranslate" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Solamente tengo esos cuatro elementos, y lo dicho, necesito centrarlos a los 4 verticalmente, ya que horizontalmente ya los tengo centrados. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Selecciona en modo `Editor`, selecciona todos los elementos y presiona click izquierdo ->`Center`->`Vertically`, [Documentacion Oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0) quizas es lo que intentas lograr.

Comment: Si y no, porque esto me centra cada elemento, yo quería centrar los cuatro en conjunto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, ya lo he solucionado yo mismo, he creado otro Constraint Layout que encierre los elementos, de tamaño `wrap content` tanto alto como ancho, le añado las constrains y listo, dejo el código para quien le sirva, aunque si hay una solución mejor soy todo ojos:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Intridici il tixti"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBeforeTranslate"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAfterTranslate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Intridici il tixti"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etBeforeTranslate" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAfterTranslate"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAfterTranslate" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Qué onda amigos.

Una solución más fácil es crear un chain a los cuatro elementos.
Para hacer eso lo único que tienes que hacer es seleccionar el primer TextView y presionar/mantener "shift" y seleccionar los demás elementos. (Esto en la pestaña de Design).

Una vez seleccionados todos los elementos debes de dar click derecho en cualquier elemento y seleccionar Chains -> Create vertical chain.

Y listo. por default se acomodan centrados de forma vertical, ocupando toda la pantalla.

Dejo el código generado por el IDE Android Studio.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intridici il tixti"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etBeforeTranslate"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etBeforeTranslate"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvAfterTranslate"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAfterTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intridici il tixti"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etAfterTranslate"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etBeforeTranslate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAfterTranslate"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAfterTranslate" />
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Pero estamos en el mismo supuesto que la respuesta que me ha dado el compañero, lo centra verticalmente a lo largo de toda la vista padre, yo quiero que me centre los elementos juntos.

Comment: Lo unico que tienes que hacer es agregar este atributo a los cuatro elementos de tu constraint   app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"